# Como separar valores de uma variável em php?

Tags: php

Como separar valores de uma variável e guardar em variáveis separadas?

Exemplo:

```
$valores = '12';
```

Como separar e guardar em outras variáveis? Assim:

```
$primeiroValor = 1;
$segundoValor = 2;
```

Comment: Esses valores estão separados por algum delimitador?

Comment: ter tem só precisa ter um delimitador algo do gênero para fazer sentido

Comment: O tamanho é sempre o mesmo? No caso é sempre 2 caracteres? Se for é só fazer assim: `$primeiroValor = $valores[0]; $segundoValor = $valores[1];`

Comment: nesse caso você gostaria de tratar com variáveis do tipo string e não inteiros, correto?
Strings em PHP são cadeias de caracteres, daria pra puxar cada valor pelo índice dele, depois concatenar os dois e passar para int

Comment: vai ser sempre dois valores... seráo o ID das notícias...pois  logo abaixo eu irei exibir outras notícias, mas tem que ser diferente dessas que tenho que separar...

Comment: OK, é o ID da notícia como disse, mas não terá como chegar na notícia 100 por exemplo, dai já irão para 3 digitos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra solução seria separar caracter por caracter de modo que você tenha cada um para fazer oque deseja.
Exemplo, mostrando cada caracter de uma string em uma linha;

```
$palavra = "teste";
$tamPalavra = strlen($palavra);
for ($i = 0; $i < $tamPalavra; $i++) {
  echo 'Caracter ' . $i . ' = ' . $palavra[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

A saida deste código será algo como:
Caracter 1 = t
Caracter 2 = e
Caracter 3 = s
Caracter 4 = t
Caracter 5 = e

Este código lhe permite trabalhar com uma string de tamanho desconhecido e realizar a manipulação que desejar livremente.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, você pode usar o método split, segue como funciona e exemplos.

Este método "quebra" a string utilizando um delimitador setado por você e retorna uma array.

Exemplo:

> Split(pattern,string, limit)

```
$strExemple = "este/e/um/exemplo";
$teste = split ('/', $strExemple);
// Saída
// $teste[0] = "este";
// $teste[1] = "e";
// $teste[2] = "um";
// $teste[3] = "exemplo";
```

Comment: Acho que nesse caso seria um desperdício...
Imagina só: $strExemple = "1/2";

Não considera mais fácil como o @Earendul comentou ali em cima?

Comment: Seria ..mas já aproveitei pra ensinar pra caso aconteça em algum ambiente diferente no qual ele precise separar por outras regras =)

Comment: `split` encontra-se depreciada pelo PHP (E_DEPRECATED). Ao invés dele deve-se usar `explode`ou `preg_split` (sendo mais indicada nesse caso o `explode`)

Answer (score 3):

Como é sempre dois caracteres então é só fazer assim:

```
$valores = '12';

$primeiroValor = $valores[0];
$segundoValor = $valores[1];
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas dicas! Deu certo com a resposta do Earendul!

Obrigado!!!

Comment: E se $valores um inteiro ?

Comment: Aí você pode converter para string. Ou então, como é sempre 2 caracteres, pode dividir o número por 10, a parte inteira da divisão vai ser o `primeiroValor` e o resto da divisão o `segundoValor`

Answer (score 0):

Ambas as respostas estão certas mas tudo depende do modo que é pretendido para a obter o desejado.

Assim, se o pretendido é separar carácter a carácter então a resposta do 'Earendul' é a melhor opção. No entanto e caso a separação carácter a carácter não seja o indicado, é recomendável a solução do 'Wisner Oliveira'... Dito isto queria complementar a resposta com o seguinte:

1. O Split utiliza "regular expressions" o que em muitos casos reduz a performance e a partir da versão 5.3 do php será um comando "decrepated" portanto de evitar.
2. Existe o preg_split que é referido ser mais rápido entre 25% a 50% quando comparado com o Split
3. Se o caso for delimitar por um carácter ou conjunto de caracteres então na maior parte dos casos o "explode" é a solução mais eficiente.

Espero ter ajudado.